# Por que que tenho de indicar o endereço completo? <img src...>

Tags: imagem, html

Estou a tentar fazer o meu primeiro site.

De momento não entendo porque que, ao inserir imagens tenho de inserir o endereço completo, visto que em todos os blogs e sites de HTML, isso não é necessário. A imagem está noutra pasta. Alguém me ajuda?

O seguinte funciona:

```
<img src="/home/rafa/Desktop/Curriculum Vitae/imagens/hall.jpg" alt="Foto inicial">
```

Este já não:

```
<img src="/imagens/hall.jpg" alt="Foto inicial">
```

Comment: Mas em que sítio da página é que estás ao ver as imagens? Na página `Curriculum Vitae`?

Comment: Você hospedou seu site em algum servidor? Ou está só abrindo o HTML puro via arquivo, sem servidor http?

Comment: Sim sim. Não estou a usar nenhum servidor, estou apenas a experimentar em HTML puro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se sua página HTML estiver no mesmo nível da pasta imagens, no caso dentro da pasta Curriculum Vitae, você conseguirá acessar a imagem fazendo `src=imagens/hall.jpg` ou fazendo `src=./imagens/hall.jpg`.
Da forma que você fez, o navegador está procurando a pasta imagens no diretório /.